# macOS zsh terminal $HOST displays .ht.home

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I've been tinkering with my `.zshrc` file for a while to change how the command prompt looks and also make it display certain statuses for git. But after I made some changes
when I type in `echo $HOST` to see the hostname of my laptop, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dym4r.png) shows up. (narnia is just what I named the hostname) It used to show narnia.local, but now it shows narnia.ht.home. Could someone explain what caused this to change, and whether or not it's something I should worry about?

Comment: The title of your question refers to the variable _HOSTNAME_, while the text of your question refers to the variable _HOST_. Which one are you actually interested in? _HOST_ is a variable automatically set by zsh, while _HOSTNAME_ isn't.

Comment: @user1934428 yeah sorry, i was referring to *HOST*

Comment: I don't see how this question is related to zsh. For setting the `HOST` variable, zsh has to query the operating system for the name of the host, and it simply will use what value it gets in return. I don't think that there is much additional magic going on.